# Some Content Search web parts have RefinableString01 available, and some don't. Can someone tell me how to get it available universally?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, content-search-web-part, refiner

I have Content Search web parts on several different pages (SPO).  In the Refiners list, sometimes the RefinableString01 is available, and sometimes it isn't.  Can anyone tell me how to make it universally available?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Build Your Query dialog box, go to BASICS tab, make sure that you select the same result source, restrict and set the same query text for the result. Then go to REFINERS tab to check if the refiners exists.
[image]